# use Ajax to call data from servlet

Tags: ajax, jsp, servlets

I know this question probably has been asked before, but I can't seem to find the awnser on it.

I'm trying to call a servlet method when a page is loaded, at this moment it's an endless loop cause every time the servlet posts the response the page gets reloaded and calls the servlet again which then calls reloads the page again etc etc..

I'm collecting an ID from the url which I then use in the servlet to collect the data I need.
Here is the code I'm currently using.

```
<form style="display:none;" action="ServletC" method="POST">
                <input type="hidden" name="hdn_parameter" value="<%= request.getParameter("productID")%>"/>
                <input type="submit" id="btn_loadform" name="loadform" style="display: none;"/>
                <script>

                        document.getElementById('btn_loadform').click();
                </script>
            </form>
```

and I got a couple pieces of code like this throughout the page

```
<img id="picture_img" class="" style="width:300px;" src="${ImageResponse}" />
```

The following code is on my servlet

```
if (request.getParameter("loadform") != null)
    {
            int productID = Integer.parseInt(request.getParameter("hdn_parameter"));
            String link = "PictureDetail.jsp?productID=" + Integer.toString(productID);
            Product p = null;
             try 
             {
                  p = DBConnect.getProduct(productID);
             } 
             catch (SQLException ex) 
             {
                 Logger.getLogger(ServletC.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
             }

            request.setAttribute("ImageResponse", p.getPath());
            request.setAttribute("TitleResponse", p.getName());
            request.setAttribute("DescriptionResponse", p.getDescription());
            request.setAttribute("PriceResponse", p.getPrice());
            loaded = true;
            RequestDispatcher dis = request.getRequestDispatcher(link);
            dis.forward(request, response);
    }
```

could anyone help me on what I should do now to make this happen without refreshing the page so it will work smoothly.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you  redirect the page then in ajax you will get response.i.e actual HTML code. you will get redirected page HTML.if you want to redirect and load that page with out ajax

Answer (score 0):

The request that goes out on click of that button is a proper http request and its response would naturally repaint the page. You will have to form an AJAX request on button click, parse the response on success and then do something on the page (with the parsed response data).

Comment: could you tell me how to do this exactly, I know nothing about ajax